# How do I selectively edit or skip certain lines using SED

Tags: sed

Say I want to substitute test for TEST, but not after a "!"  The substitution should be ignored after the "!" but not before.

And I also want to skip lines containing the word "skipme"

eg:

```
test
! test
test ! test
blahblah ! test
blah skipme test
test
```

should become:

```
TEST
! test
TEST ! test
blahblah ! test
blah skipme test
TEST
```

Comment: Why don't you use awk ?

Comment: Is the `test` to change always the first world in the line, or can you have `blah test ! test`  that needs to become `blah TEST ! test`

Answer (score 0):

`^` perhaps is all you need.

```
sed -e 's|^test|TEST|' your_file.txt
```

Outputs:

```
TEST
! test
TEST ! test
blahblah ! test
blah skipme test
TEST
```

As some notes in `grep`:

> The caret ^ and the dollar sign $ are meta-characters that
>   respectively match the empty string at the beginning and end of a
>   line.

Comment: What about a line `my test`?  Its not mention that line needs to be started by `test`

Comment: @Jotne I don't see `my test` anywhere in his examples.

Comment: No, but its just a test example. Problem is to change `test` to `TEST`, but not after `!` nor `skipme` (nothing mention that it need to be the first word)

Comment: Well we can see if that's what the OP explicitly mean.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk '{f=0;for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~/!|skipme/) f=1; if (!f && $i=="test") $i=toupper($i)}}1' file
TEST
! test
TEST ! test
blahblah ! test
blah skipme test
TEST
```

---

How it works

```
awk '{
    f=0                         # set flag to 0
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {       # run trough all fields one by one
        if ($i~/!|skipme/)      # if a field contains "!" or "skipme"
            f=1                 # set flag "f" to "1"
        if (!f && $i=="test")   # If field contains "test" and flag "f" is not set, do
            $i=toupper($i)      # Set field to upper characters
        }
    }
1                               # Print the line
' file                          # Read the file
```

---

An updated version of Jidders version that should work i most cases:
(this will not work if there are more than on `test` to change, but
It will work even if there are no space between words)

```
awk '(/!/ && index($0,w)<index($0,"!")) || (/skipme/ && index($0,w)<index($0,"skipme")) || !/!|skipme/ {c=toupper(w);sub(w,c)}1' w="test" file
```

Comment: This is probz better than mine

Answer (score 0):

And the one through perl,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(?<!\! )test/TEST/ unless /skipme/' file
TEST
! test
TEST ! test
blahblah ! test
blah skipme test
TEST
```

It replaces `test` with `TEST` only when it is not preceeded by `!` and skips the line which contains the  string `skipme`.

Comment: Its not in OPs example, but this will fail for lines like `blah test skipme more test` and `test skipme test`

Comment: @Jotne he wants to skip the lines which contains `skipme`.

Comment: No, I think he meas I want to skip changing of `test` to `TEST` for lines with `skipme`, but that could go either way.

Comment: HE means, i don't want to replace the word `test` to `TEST` if the line contains `skipme`.

Comment: `test for TEST, but not after a "!" > And I also want to skip lines containing the word "skipme"`. For me that can mean do not change test after skipme. We have to wait to OP responds to make it clear.